# Share text box is editable

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, sharing, share-this

When you click the share button under a post, a small popup will appear.
There is a link in a text box to the post that you would like to share.

The problem I've encountered is that I accidentally typed into the link text box, which totally ruined the link, forcing me to close the popup and re-open it.

I do not see why anyone would want to modify the link in any way, since modifying it would completely ruin the purpose of the link, as it might be an invalid url or a link to a different post. I suggest that the text box should not be editable.

I'm not a good programmer, but I found a link to a possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3676132/3696113).

Comment: Does it matter though? I don't know why, but I do even find it convenient.

Comment: Agree with @nicael! The fact that it's editable makes it really easy for scripts to change the URL to things like markdownified URLs (like `[title](url)`). Besides, there's always Ctrl+Z :)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ actually script can change readonly textbox without any problem, the readonly attribute prevents only changing the value by the user. (e.g. typing, pasting)

Comment: Meh.  When I use it, I hit ctrl-x, which copies to the clipboard and removes the text.  That gives me a visual indication that the copy has actually occurred.  I cannot tell you how often, and how incredibly baby-punchingly annoying, it happens that I think I've copied something to the clipboard but the operation failed for some unknown reason.  The visual I get with ctrl-x makes this impossible.  Note, I do this *everywhere*.  My usual copy pattern is "ctrl-x, ctrl-v *moves to paste destination* ctrl-v"

Comment: @ShadowWizard you're right... but there's still ctrl+z :P

Answer (score 5):

I'm just so used to it being a textbox rather than a readonly input / span, that it'll really be weird if it is changed. Some arguments I've thought up:

- being a textbox as such, it provides an easy workaround to make the text distinguishable from the background. If it's made readonly, I'd expect complaints that the textbox doesn't function.
- often I leave the id part out to shorten the link, and I've get used to do this right in the "share" textbox
- unless you have your keyboard invaded by your cat, I'd think it's pretty rare to accidentally type there something, never faced that.